# Survival Function of Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

My text The Statistical Evaluation of Medical Tests for Classification and Prediction contains the following, (Where I have simplified notation to avoid writing too many definitions)

> If $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and we have that $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distributive function then for a threshold value $c$ we have that $P(Y>c) = \Phi(\frac{\mu-c}{\sigma})$.

To me, we should have $P(Y>c) = 1 - F(c) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma})$. This should be a simple rearangement, but I cannot see how these two are equal.

Comment: $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ (why?)

Comment: We have $\Phi(-x) + \Phi(x) = 1$ since $\Phi(-x) = P(Y>x)$. Right?

Comment: Yes. The bell curve is symmetric around the $y$-axis.

Comment: Great, thank you!